# Can't export data from a database to a csv file

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to gather data off a database on the cloud and export every attribute and tuple onto a csv file.

```
static final String JBDC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jbdc.Driver";

public static void main(String[]args){
    String filename = "c:/users/myjbdcfile.csv";

    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename);
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,user,pass);
        String query  = "select * from allSavedSongs";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            fw.append(rs.getString(1));
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append(rs.getString(2));
            fw.append(',');
            fw.append(rs.getString(3));
            fw.append(',');

        }
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I'm getting the error *java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\users\myjbdcfile.csv (Access is denied)* I also tried doing String filename = "c:\users\myjdbcfile.csv";

Comment: In the cloud which you may get a unix vm, how will you get C:/ drive there ?

Comment: @Sambit I'm trying to get it off of google cloud and pull the data to a csv on my hard drive

Comment: Do you run this code with access privileges to `"c:/users/"`? Have you tried using `String filename = "c:\\users\\myjdbcfile.csv"`?

Comment: how would make it to access with privileges. and ya I tried that @deHaar

Comment: Maybe, your current user in Windows does not have access to `"c:\users\"` but to `"c:\users\YOUR_CURRENT_USERNAME\"`, try to create the file in the directory of your current user.

Answer (score 0):

Usually C:/Users will not have permissions to write, unless you modify the permissions.
I would prefer not to modify the permissions and use different drive or folder.

```
       String filename = "D:/users/myjbdcfile.csv";
        File dbFile = new File(filename);
        dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        dbFile.createNewFile();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dbFile);
```

Also you are writing the data to file for each record which will impact the performance.
Use StringBuilder and List and build the logic around it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider approach without writing a java code at all? With IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate you can simply [export sql results](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editing-csv-and-tsv-files.html#copy-data) into a [file](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/export-data-in-ide.html#export-to-a-file):

[image]

of CSV or any custom format you want by [creating a custom extractor script](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extending-the-product-functionality.html#c0eb364d).